# Error TS7053 - ao tentar criar um método pra abter uma lista do back end

Tags: angularjs, angular

O elemento implicitamente tem um tipo 'any' porque a expressão do tipo '"cursos"' não pode ser usada para o tipo de índice 'Object'.
A propriedade 'cursos' não existe no tipo 'Object'.ts(7053)

```
export class CursoService {

  //URL base da API 
  url = "http://localhost/api/php/";

  //Vetor de cursos
  vetor:Curso[] = [];

  

  // Contrutor
  constructor(
    // Module para acesso ao banco de dados
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }


  // Metodos de Seleção 
  // Obter cursos
  obterCurso():Observable<Curso[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.url+"listar").pipe(
      map((res) => {
       this.vetor = res['cursos']; // <<< Error
       return this.vetor
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Já deu um **console.log()** pra ver o que vem da Api em **`res`**? Pode ser que não seja o que esteja pensando.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

O parâmetro res dentro do map() é do tipo *Object*. como a imagem abaixo mostra.

[image: Imagem do tipo do parâmetro]

É por isso  que o erro aparece pois não existe "cursos" no tipo Objeto. apenas coloquei o tipo do *res* como *any* que o erro desapareceu.

```
 public getCursos(): Observable<Curso[]> {
   return this.http.get('http://localhost:3333/phones' , { responseType: 'text'} ).pipe(map(
     (res: any) => {
       console.log(res);
       this.cursos = res['cursos']
       return this.cursos;
     }
   ))
 }
```

Comment: eu coloquei o any,, o erro no vsCode desapareceu, porem continuo sem receber as informação da API

Comment: acrescente um log e compartilhe o que é retornado para que eu possa ajudar mais

Comment: o logo dentro do metodo não funciona,  no inspecionar do navegar aparece esse erro aqui :

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHQkI.png

Comment: quando coloco any aparece esse erro no console :

[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHQkI.png

Comment: este erro esta ocorrendo pois o angular não esta conseguindo converter o  que recebe da api em um objeto json. caso realmente não seja json coloque o tipo do retorno. Ex: se for do tipo text coloque **responseType: 'text'** nas options do método get (vou modificar minha resposta acima com esse exemplo).  Agora caso realmente sua intensão receber no formato json você deve investigar o que esta send retornado da api. tente usar o insominia ou postman pra saber qual o retorno.

Comment: o resultado do log esta esse :

Comment: array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["idCurso"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["nomeCurso"]=>
    string(7) "Angular"
    ["valorCurso"]=>
    string(6) "850.00"
  }
}

Answer (score -2):

O resultado do log :

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["idCurso"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["nomeCurso"]=>
    string(7) "Angular"
    ["valorCurso"]=>
    string(6) "850.00"
  }
}
```

so que a vetor esta retornando undefined

o back-end esta assim:

```
<?php 

// Inluindo a conexão 
include("conexao.php");

//Comando sql
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cursos";

// Executar
$executar = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

// Vetor 
$cursos = [];

// Indice 
$indice = 0; 

// laço buscando linha a linha e adicionando no vetor 
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($executar)){
    $cursos[$indice]['idCurso'] = $linha['idCurso'];
    $cursos[$indice]['nomeCurso'] = $linha['nomeCurso'];
    $cursos[$indice]['valorCurso'] = $linha['valorCurso'];

    $indice++;
}

// Encapsular no JSON
json_encode(['cursos'=>$cursos]);

// Exibindo dados 
var_dump($cursos);
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Giovane, conseguiu resolver esse problema? Estou com a mesma situação...

tenho esse retorno do console...

Angular is running in development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable production mode.
curso.service.ts:21

null

core.mjs:7640 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'curso')
at curso.service.ts:22:26
at map.js:7:37

Comment: eu acabei desistindo. =(

Answer (score -3):

Não sei se serve a resposta, mas eu também estou fazendo esse curso e o problema é que o Angular mais recente, agora tem que definir os tipos de tudo e inicializar as variáveis que no curso não era obrigatório, talvez por ser uma versão mais antiga do Angular. Outra alteração que eu fiz para não retornar nulo foi no PHP, eu não sei se foi isso, quem tem mais experiência pode me corrigir:

```
//JSON
echo json_encode(["cursos" => $cursos]);
```

No exemplo do curso não tem esse echo, porque ele só mostrou com o var_dump na tela